# How do I set a invisible default value in entry widgets?

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

I'm making a small app with Gtk3 and Glade that calculates volumes, it has a lot of entry widgets and for calculation purposes I need them to be set to `0` by default. That's easily done in Glade but I want the `0` to be invisible.

Is there a way to make the default value of the entry invisible or to apply a conditional like:

```
if entry = None:
    entry = 0
```

to all the entry widgets without repeating myself endlessly?

Comment: Does it need to be an Entry widget, or will a SpinButton work as well since it sounds like numeric data is being used?

Comment: Yes, it's only numeric data being used and a SpinButton would do the job. The input will be floats with values high up in the thousands and the SpinButton would feel out of place, also removing these `0` is just a cosmetic thing and a SpinButton would make it worse I think. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on implementing the decimal module instead of using floats, I then wrote a small function to check for input.

```
def num(entry):
    number = Decimal(0.00) if not entry else Decimal(entry)
    return number
```

Works fine and seems like the best solution. At least that's what I'm going for.